# 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, self

working on ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7
I have the error 'list' object has no attribute 'items' when I call the print_to_screen function.
could someone explain me please how to manage the dictionary which is created?
Thanks

class median_uniq:
    def **init**(self):
        self.median_number_list = []

```
def print_to_screen(self, words_dict, is_reverse = False):
    words = words_dict.items()
    words.sort(key = lambda(a,b):(a,b), reverse = is_reverse)
    print("[Words tweeted: %d]" % len(words)).center(60,"=")
    print("%-25s | %25s" % ("Words", "count"))
    print BANNER
    for w, c in words:
        print("%-25s | %25d" % (w, c))

def Median_number(self, file_name):
    file_object = open(file_name, "r")
    number_word_list = []
    for line in file_object:
       unique_words_per_tweet = sorted(set(line.rstrip().split(" ")))
       number_word_list.append(len(Counter((unique_words_per_tweet))))
       self.median_number_list.append(numpy.median(numpy.array(number_word_list)))
       print self.median_number_list
       return  self.median_number_list
```

to call function, I do this:

med = median_uniq() med_list = med.Median_number(input_file)

med.print_to_screen(med_list, is_reverse = False)

on command line knowing that my input_file is a .txt file. thanks

I have seen similar post, but don't well understand. An explanation with simply words would be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: where do you call `print_to_screen`?

Comment: Actually I do this:
 med = median_uniq()
med_list = med.Median_number(input_file)
med.print_to_screen(med_list, is_reverse = False) 
on command line knowing that my input_file is a .txt file.
thanks

Comment: can you [edit] your question to include the new information please (with formatting :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"words_dict" in your code is a list, but your attempt to use a python dictionary method (items())

I would need a working example to be able to propose a customized solution.

Comment: my input file look like this:

Comment: my input file is a text file with this 
[Whether it's for the 
birth of your baby, ...]

and my output will be:
Words                     |                     count
------------------------------------------------------------
Whether                   |                         2
baby,                     |                         1
birth                     |                         1
for                       |                         2
it's                      |                         2

Comment: hopefully I gave you what you need